# WIndows 8 BSOD XBMC

Tags: windows-8, bsod, kodi

I am receiving frequent BSODs in Windows 8, which are either BAD_POOL_HEADER or DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION but it only happens after [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) has been running.

[WhoCrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed) and told me this:

> ### System Information (local)
>
> computer name: CMSL42-DESKTOP windows version: Windows 8 , 6.2, build:
>   9200 windows dir: C:\Windows CPU: AuthenticAMD AMD Phenom(tm) II X6
>   1090T Processor AMD586, level: 16 6 logical processors, active mask:
>   63 RAM: 16641871872 total VM: 2147352576, free: 1927999488
>
> ---
>
> ### Crash Dump Analysis
>
> Crash dump directory: C:\Windows\Minidump
>
> Crash dumps are enabled on your computer.
>
> On Mon 22/07/2013 12:05:06 PM GMT your computer crashed crash dump
>   file: C:\Windows\Minidump\072213-33649-01.dmp This was probably caused
>   by the following module: tcpip.sys (tcpip+0xDB024)  Bugcheck code:
>   0x19 (0xD, 0xFFFFF880180041E0, 0xFFFFF88001D94024, 0x9239D5B78D234E2E)
>   Error: BAD_POOL_HEADER file path:
>   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys product: Microsoft® Windows®
>   Operating System company: Microsoft Corporation description: TCP/IP
>   Driver Bug check description: This indicates that a pool header is
>   corrupt. This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not
>   likely to be caused by a hardware problem. This might be a case of
>   memory corruption. More often memory corruption happens because of
>   software errors in buggy drivers, not because of faulty RAM modules. 
>   The crash took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system
>   configuration may be incorrect. Possibly this problem is caused by
>   another driver on your system that cannot be identified at this time.
>
> On Mon 22/07/2013 12:05:06 PM GMT your computer crashed crash dump
>   file: C:\Windows\memory.dmp This was probably caused by the following
>   module: nvlddmkm.sys (nvlddmkm+0x18A14F)  Bugcheck code: 0x19 (0xD,
>   0xFFFFF880180041E0, 0xFFFFF88001D94024, 0x9239D5B78D234E2E) Error:
>   BAD_POOL_HEADER file path: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\nvlddmkm.sys
>   product: NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 320.49  company:
>   NVIDIA Corporation description: NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver,
>   Version 320.49  Bug check description: This indicates that a pool
>   header is corrupt. This appears to be a typical software driver bug
>   and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. This might be a
>   case of memory corruption. More often memory corruption happens
>   because of software errors in buggy drivers, not because of faulty RAM
>   modules.  A third party driver was identified as the probable root
>   cause of this system error. It is suggested you look for an update for
>   the following driver: nvlddmkm.sys (NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver,
>   Version 320.49 , NVIDIA Corporation).  Google query: NVIDIA
>   Corporation BAD_POOL_HEADER
>
> On Sun 21/07/2013 8:25:06 PM GMT your computer crashed crash dump
>   file: C:\Windows\Minidump\072213-30045-01.dmp This was probably caused
>   by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x5A440)  Bugcheck code:
>   0x133 (0x1, 0x1E0D, 0x0, 0x0) Error: DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION file path:
>   C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe product: Microsoft® Windows®
>   Operating System company: Microsoft Corporation description: NT Kernel
>   & System Bug check description: The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged
>   run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL or above. This appears to be a
>   typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a
>   hardware problem. This problem might be caused by a thermal issue. 
>   The crash took place in the Windows kernel. Possibly this problem is
>   caused by another driver that cannot be identified at this time.
>
> On Sun 21/07/2013 5:04:34 PM GMT your computer crashed crash dump
>   file: C:\Windows\Minidump\072213-29343-01.dmp This was probably caused
>   by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x5A440)  Bugcheck code:
>   0x133 (0x1, 0x1E0D, 0x0, 0x0) Error: DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION file path:
>   C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe product: Microsoft® Windows®
>   Operating System company: Microsoft Corporation description: NT Kernel
>   & System Bug check description: The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged
>   run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL or above. This appears to be a
>   typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a
>   hardware problem. This problem might be caused by a thermal issue. 
>   The crash took place in the Windows kernel. Possibly this problem is
>   caused by another driver that cannot be identified at this time.
>
> On Sun 21/07/2013 4:31:53 PM GMT your computer crashed crash dump
>   file: C:\Windows\Minidump\072213-41153-01.dmp This was probably caused
>   by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x5A440)  Bugcheck code:
>   0x19 (0xD, 0xFFFFF880184921E0, 0x0, 0x1E5DDB866E4D06BA) Error:
>   BAD_POOL_HEADER file path: C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe product:
>   Microsoft® Windows® Operating System company: Microsoft Corporation
>   description: NT Kernel & System Bug check description: This indicates
>   that a pool header is corrupt. This appears to be a typical software
>   driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. This
>   might be a case of memory corruption. More often memory corruption
>   happens because of software errors in buggy drivers, not because of
>   faulty RAM modules.  The crash took place in the Windows kernel.
>   Possibly this problem is caused by another driver that cannot be
>   identified at this time.
>
> On Mon 15/07/2013 1:00:49 PM GMT your computer crashed crash dump
>   file: C:\Windows\Minidump\071513-75426-01.dmp This was probably caused
>   by the following module: tcpip.sys (tcpip+0xDB798)  Bugcheck code:
>   0x19 (0xD, 0xFFFFF880153481E0, 0xFFFFF88001D57798, 0xCBFD93B7E3826D86)
>   Error: BAD_POOL_HEADER file path:
>   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys product: Microsoft® Windows®
>   Operating System company: Microsoft Corporation description: TCP/IP
>   Driver Bug check description: This indicates that a pool header is
>   corrupt. This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not
>   likely to be caused by a hardware problem. This might be a case of
>   memory corruption. More often memory corruption happens because of
>   software errors in buggy drivers, not because of faulty RAM modules. 
>   The crash took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system
>   configuration may be incorrect. Possibly this problem is caused by
>   another driver on your system that cannot be identified at this time.

Comment: I would report the issue to the developer of XBMC. The `BAD_POOL_HEADER` is likely caused by bad drivers or a hdd about to fail.  Without additional details its unlikely the information you posted is very helpful.  It doesn't even tell you what cause the crash.

Comment: upload the .dmp files so that we can look at them with WinDbg

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/rar/WmCb6sV2/DMP.html

Comment: use a different hoster which is completely free. I don't register just to download the dumps.

Comment: Sorry didnt know you had to sign up to download try this http://www.filedropper.com/dmp

Comment: I also can't download from there. Use zippyshare.com, putlocker.com or mediafire.com

Comment: http://www57.zippyshare.com/v/95877985/file.html

Answer (score 0):

You get several different crashes.

2 dumps show a DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION bugcheck:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj154556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000001, The system cumulatively spent an extended period of time at
    DISPATCH_LEVEL or above. The offending component can usually be
    identified with a stack trace.
Arg2: 0000000000001e0d, The watchdog period.
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  DPC_QUEUE_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x133

PROCESS_NAME:  networx.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  d

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9431.0 (debuggers(dbg).130615-1214) amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80341661fa3 to fffff803414e2440

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
nt!KeUpdateTime
hal!HalpTimerClockInterrupt
nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw
nt!KxWaitForLockOwnerShip
tcpip!UdpSendMessages
tcpip!UdpTlProviderSendMessagesCalloutRoutine
nt!KeExpandKernelStackAndCalloutInternal
nt!KeExpandKernelStackAndCalloutEx
tcpip!UdpTlProviderSendMessages
tdx!TdxSendDatagramTransportAddress
tdx!TdxTdiDispatchInternalDeviceControl
networx
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
networx
0x0


IMAGE_NAME:  tdx.sys

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.2.9200.16384

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x133_ISR_tdx!TdxSendDatagramTransportAddress

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x133_isr_tdx!tdxsenddatagramtransportaddress


    Loaded symbol image file: networx.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\networx.sys
    Image name: networx.sys
    Timestamp:        Thu Jul 12 11:01:07 2012
```

In this case update the driver `networx.sys`

The other dumps show a BAD_POOL_HEADER crash:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The last driver which accesses data is the nVIDIA GPU driver. But it doesn't mean that this driver causes the crashes.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

BAD_POOL_HEADER (19)
The pool is already corrupt at the time of the current request.
This may or may not be due to the caller.
The internal pool links must be walked to figure out a possible cause of
the problem, and then special pool applied to the suspect tags or the driver
verifier to a suspect driver.
Arguments:
Arg1: 000000000000000d, 
Arg2: fffff880180041e0
Arg3: fffff88001d94024
Arg4: 9239d5b78d234e2e

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x19_d

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8013be781f0 to fffff8013bc60440

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!ExFreePool
nt!ExFreePoolWithTag
nvlddmkm
nt!IopProcessWorkItem
nt!ExpWorkerThread
nt!PspSystemThreadStartup
nt!KiStartSystemThread

Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys
Image name: nvlddmkm.sys
Timestamp:        Fri Jun 21 11:06:16 2013
```

You have to activate driver verifier:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-16-WinDbg-Driver-Verifier
http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-17-WinDbg-Driver-Verifier-Part-2
http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-18-WinDbg-Driver-Verifier-Part-3

and upload the new memory.dmp which is generated.